# How to prevent macOS from switching back to previous language?

Tags: macos, keyboard, big-sur, input-source, apple-silicon

I have MacBook Pro with M1, macOS BigSur 11.4. It has special key with globe icon to change input method.

When I press it a little window shows up indicating the switching of an input method. And if cursor is above the previous input method then this window detects cursor, thinks I choose it deliberately and switches back.

How can I prevent such behaviour?

[image]

**UPD** This window only appears if I press Fn (globe) key. If I check "Use the Caps Lock key to switch to and from ABS" in keyboard settings and press Caps it won't show up and language switches as expected. I don't even understand why do you need such window and if for some reason they want to indicate language switching why it detects cursor input.

Comment: see e.g. https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/469076/46418