# How do I disable language switch popup?

Tags: macos, keyboard, language, input-source

I'm a new member of apple products community and I'm learning how to setup a process I've got used to. One of inconveniences is language switch. When I'm trying to change language I get a popup with language list (see pic below). The problem is it introduces a small delay before change actually applies (which meh but I can live with it) and the bigger problem that if your mouse is around screen center then mouse pointer overrides language selection and you can stuck with one language unless you move the cursor somewhere

[image]

I wonder if there is any way to workaround it with OS X built in tools. I'd really like to not install any 3rd party tools or assigning switch to another key - this one works just fine, the only problem is this pop up.

Comment: What key are you using to switch?  Fn, Capslock, or control space?  Try all three and see which works best for you.     https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/write-in-another-language-on-your-mac-mchlp1406/12.0/mac/12.0

Comment: It's a FN key (with globe painted on it). It's MBP2021. I'd like to not use capslock or ctrl+space if possible, Fn works just fine except this one problem. I wonder if I can keep using it but hide just popup

Comment: Fixed in MacOS 14...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macos 14 removed this popup so the question is therefore answered.

Comment: The new popup is horrible, it's a mess and has a really bad delay. Thankfully there's a solution at https://github.com/Nikeev/LangSwitch for future readers :)

Answer (score 5):

I fixed this problem by redirecting <kbd>fn</kbd> (change input source) to <kbd>Left Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> (previous input source) through a complex rule for Karabiner-Elements. This fix involves a 3rd party app, but I am not sure whether it is possible to fix this problem without such apps. The key for changing the input source remains the same.

Note that in the **Keyboard** section of **System Preferences** the <kbd>fn</kbd>(globe) should be put to "Do Nothing" in the **Keyboard** tab and the previous input source shortcut to <kbd>Left Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> in **Hotkeys** tab.

The complex rule was added to the app through the karabiner.json file in the .config folder.
The rule is:

```
`{
   "description":"fn -> previous input source",
   "manipulators":[
      {
         "from":{
            "key_code":"fn"
         },
         "to":[
            {
               "key_code":"fn"
            }
         ],
         "to_if_alone":[
            {
               "key_code":"spacebar",
               "modifiers":[
                  "left_control"
               ]
            }
         ],
         "type":"basic"
      }
   ]
}`
```

Comment: this is not good solution if your keyboard have special language switch button.

Comment: This is a perfect solution, thank you a lot! Just don't forget to disable standard language switch for fn in keyboard->keyboard. Fast language switch without any ugly pop-ups, I am so happy!

Answer (score 1):

Working solution: https://github.com/norflin321/fn-lang-switcher.
With use of python script, but the result is identical except there is no popup and not way to select wrong language with mouse, and it works a little bit faster!

Comment: Hi. Looks cool but it seems that it only supports 2 layouts and it won't probably work in my case (Russian - PC). I guess script should be a bit more sophisticated :)

Comment: i have Russian layout too, it works

Answer (score 0):

In system settings, there are 3 default keyboard shortcuts to change input source. Below only the 3rd way is **without** popup dialog:

1. change input source: <kbd>globe</kbd>
2. select the previous input source: <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>
3. select next source in input menu: <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>

[image]

If your only issue is with the popup, you may use just that.

It's shortcut is configurable to special keys, but it just doesn't accept <kbd>globe</kbd> to my dismay.

Answer (score -1):

This is actually possible without any third-party apps, the macOS System Settings are just very confusing.

To disable the annoying language switching when pressing the globe key go to: `Keyboard > Press globe key to...` and set it to `Do nothing`.

[image]

You can still use the globe key to toggle `fn`/function keys! Just make sure to keep `Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > Modifier key > Globe` set to `Globe`.

[image]

Finally, set up an alternative keyboard combo on `Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > Input sources`

[image]

Comment: I don't think you understood the question.  It asks how you can get rid of the popup menu so there is no delay in switching languages.  I think your answer just stops the user from switching languages at all.

Comment: @TomGewecke ah yes, I edit the answer to add the final step if you want that

Comment: @TomGewecke although the question says "it introduces a small delay before change actually applies (which meh but I can live with it)"

Comment: Isn't that just the same answer given by Sinkeat last August, namely  use a different shortcut?  The OP also told us he wanted to keep using Fn/Globe without the popup.

Comment: no, my answer allows the globe key to still toggle between fn keys and function keys...