# Disabling language popup when changing languages on iPad

Tags: keyboard, ipad, language

My problem seems to be similar to [this one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/433797/how-do-i-disable-language-switch-popup) but I'm not sure how to apply this to an iPad.

Basically, I use a keyboard to type with my iPad frequently and whenever I switch languages I get a language list pop-up thing. This is normally fine but the problem is that I have to wait until the pop-up disappears to continue typing which is frankly a little annoying.

Just wondering how I may go about disabling this on an iPad. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using the Globe key to switch?  Try using Control Space instead.  Or Caps Lock if you are switching between Latin and non-Latin scripts.

Comment: I've been using control space until now; I don't think I've ever used the Globe key. I've thought about rebinding the keys to Caps Lock but that would be an absolute last resort.

Comment: What languages are you using?

Comment: I'm using English and Korean. Would the languages matter? I'm just under the impression that the pop-up would show regardless of the languages using.

Comment: You can use caps lock to switch those two, no rebinding of anything required.  There is a setting for it.  Try it and see if it is faster.