# Remove Fn shortcut for switching input language

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, monterey, input-source

Ever since updating to Monterey, pressing the Fn key switches the input source (language/character set). I normally press Fn+F11/F12 to change the volume, and now every time I change the volume I also change the keyboard input source, which is super annoying:

[image: Keyboard input source switching popup menu]

Going to System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts, I don't see the Fn key mentioned anywhere, and in particular nothing suspicious is listed in the Input Sources shortcuts (I have a single custom shortcut active there):

[image: Input Sources keyboard shortcuts; "Select the previous input source" is set to ^F12]

How can I disable using the Fn key to switch the keyboard input source?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can disable language switching on the <kbd>Fn</kbd>-key by choosing "Do nothing" for "Press  to ..." in `System Preferences` > `Keyboard`:

[image: Screenshot highlighting the globe key option in the Keyboard System Preferences]

Tested in macOS Monterey (v12.3.1)

Comment: macOS 14 screenshots and how to retain fn-key switching: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/469076/46418